# For each loop is not starting with the latest E-mail in the inbox, its starting with an older E-mail

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am writing an excel vba code which will loop through specified folder in outlook and get the "MailItem"s for further processing. It was working fine until there was an upgrade of MS Office suite to 2016. Now, when the loop starts, it picks the mail that was there just before the office upgrade. Why its not beginning with the latest mail that is in the folder?

Adding the code here.

I have tried to create a new macro enabled excel file and typed the code and ran it. Result is same.

```
Sub sortexcelPrintLog()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
Dim folder As Outlook.folder
Dim mitem As MailItem
Dim item As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim dirPath As String
Dim s_directory As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim checkDate As Date
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim j As Integer
Dim printLogs As Collection
Dim plog As pClass
Dim temptime As Date
Dim printlogName As String
Dim CDlogName As String
Dim logFlag As String
Dim dayname As String
Dim comparerecall As String
Dim lrow As Long

Set printLogs = New Collection


Set wb = ThisWorkbook
checkDate = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")
dayname = Format(checkDate, "dddd")
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application

Set ns = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) '.Folders("printlog")
i = 1

If dayname = "Monday" And CDate(Format(Now(), "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")) - 
TimeValue("01:00:00") > TimeValue("10:00:00 AM") Then
MsgBox folder.Name
For Each item In folder.Items
If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
Set mitem = item

If Format(item.ReceivedTime, "mm/dd/yyyy") = checkDate - 3 Then


                If (CDate(Format(mitem.ReceivedTime, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")) - 
TimeValue("01:00:00")) >= TimeValue("03:00:00 PM") Then
                        If LCase(mitem.Subject) Like LCase("Portland Claims*") Or _
                                LCase(mitem.Subject) Like LCase("Property Letter Trident Claim_TNT*") Or _
                                LCase(mitem.Subject) Like LCase("Property Letter Denver Claims*") Or _
                                LCase(mitem.Subject) Like LCase("Portland Claims*") Or _
                                LCase(mitem.Subject) Like LCase("Property Letter Alteris Claims*") Or _
                                LCase(mitem.Subject) Like LCase("Portland Claim*") Or _
                                LCase(mitem.Subject) Like LCase("recall*") Then
                            Set plog = New pClass
                            plog.Name = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(mitem.Sender, Worksheets("Agents").Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
                            plog.Subject = mitem.Subject
                            plog.SDate = Format(mitem.ReceivedTime, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                            plog.Docs = Docs(mitem.Subject)
                            plog.pages = pages(mitem.Subject)
                            plog.DTim = mitem.ReceivedTime

                            printLogs.Add plog
                        End If
                End If



        ElseIf Format(item.ReceivedTime, "mm/dd/yyyy") < checkDate - 3 
Then
            Exit For
        ElseIf Format(item.ReceivedTime, "mm/dd/yyyy") > checkDate - 3 Then
            GoTo nextbreak
        End If
         End If
nextbreak:
    Next
End If
End sub
```

I need to know why its not starting with the latest mail in the folder.

Comment: There's a `FolderPath` property of `Folder` object. Can you check if your `folder` variable points to correct folder? Maybe you receive the object of old application, before update, and it gives you some kind of backup folder.

Comment: @EganWolf Thanks for the suggestion. I tried that property with a msgbox to see what its pointing to. I got the following result _"vbaq@myemail.com\Inbox" (vbaq@myemail.com is just an example for my real E-mail address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were fortunate the mail previously processed latest first. To be sure about the order you must sort.

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortItems()

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim olFldr As Outlook.folder

    Dim olItem As Object
    Dim olFldrItems As items
    Dim mItem As MailItem

    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Do not attempt to sort items in the folder, olFldr.items, directly
    ' Sort a collection of items
    Set olFldrItems = olFldr.items
    olFldrItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

    For Each olItem In olFldrItems
        If TypeName(olItem) = "MailItem" Then
            Set mItem = olItem
            Debug.Print Format(mItem.ReceivedTime, "mm/dd/yyyy") & " " & mItem.Subject
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```